# BINANCE API - How to get Account info with User Data Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, websocket

I'm using Node and the `ws` npm package to work with WebSockets. Got the `listenKey` as stated in the docs (below), but I'm unable to get my account info using User Data Stream. I'd prefer to use a stream to read my most current account info (balances, etc) since using the Rest API to do it incurs a penalty (WEIGHT: 5) each time.

I've tried doing `ws.send('outboundAccountInfo')` but no joy.

DOCS: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/user-data-stream.md

Full code example - does not return any data:

```
import request from 'request'
import WebSocket from 'ws'

import { API_KEY } from '../../assets/secrets'


const DATA_STREAM_ENDPOINT = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws'
const BINANCE_API_ROOT = 'https://api.binance.com'
const LISTEN_KEY_ENDPOINT = `${BINANCE_API_ROOT}/api/v1/userDataStream`

const fetchAccountWebsocketData = async() => { 
  const listenKey = await fetchListenKey()

  console.log('-> ', listenKey) // valid key is returned

  let ws

  try {
    ws = await openWebSocket(`${DATA_STREAM_ENDPOINT}/${listenKey}`)
  } catch (err) {
    throw(`ERROR - fetchAccountWebsocketData: ${err}`)
  }

  // Nothing returns from either
  ws.on('message', data => console.log(data))
  ws.on('outboundAccountInfo', accountData => console.log(accountData))
}

const openWebSocket = endpoint => {
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(endpoint)

    console.log('\n-->> New Account Websocket')

    ws.on('open', () => {
      console.log('\n-->> Websocket Account open...')
      resolve(ws)
    }, err => { 
      console.log('fetchAccountWebsocketData error:', err)
      reject(err) 
    })
  })

  p.catch(err => console.log(`ERROR - fetchAccountWebsocketData: ${err}`))
  return p
}

const fetchListenKey = () => {
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      url: LISTEN_KEY_ENDPOINT, 
      headers: {'X-MBX-APIKEY': API_KEY}
    }

    request.post(options, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      if (err) 
        return reject(err)

      resolve(JSON.parse(body).listenKey)
    })
  })

  p.catch(err => console.log(`ERROR - fetchListenKey: ${err}`))
  return p
}

export default fetchAccountWebsocketData
```

Answer (score 5):

Was stuggling too .... for hours !!!

https://www.reddit.com/r/BinanceExchange/comments/a902cq/user_data_streams_has_anyone_used_it_successfully/

> The binance user data stream doesn't return anything when you connect
>   to it, only when something changes in your account. Try running your
>   code, then go to binance and place an order in the book, you should
>   see some data show up*